# Do we have a canonical question about writing files to disk, from a web page, with Javascript?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Skimming through the front page I found this question:

[Javascript Write to Textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123684/javascript-write-to-textfile)

This is something that has been asked so many times before that my first thought was "I'll just mark it as a duplicate and move on".

However, I had trouble finding a good previous question on this subject to use as a canonical question. A quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+write+file) brought no good results. I'm only finding more and more questions which I'd like to mark as duplicates as well if I ever find the canonical question I'm looking for.

Most of the questions I found are also low quality ones IMO:

- [Local JavaScript - write to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349921/local-javascript-write-to-local-file) (trying for a jQuery solution)
- [How to read and write into file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript) ("plz send me teh codez", answers for different contexts)
- [Read and write text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892824/read-and-write-text-file-in-javascript) (lacks context)
- [Javascript to read/write files on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399187/javascript-to-read-write-files-on-the-client-side) (another "plz send me teh codez")

So... Do we have a canonical answer for that? If not, I could try creating a good one.

Comment: The second one looks like a good candidate, based on the popularity of the question and its answers. Note that "gimme the codez" questions aren't strictly forbidden.

Comment: You could write your own (if all the candidates suck) and use that as the canonical.  Also, you might want to promote this question in [the javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)